# String resource cannot be found

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest, android-resources

I'm having trouble starting the app im developing - for some reason the string resources cannot be found.. 
When I start the app I get this in logCat:

```
12-20 13:44:42.156: E/AndroidRuntime(5510): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.Main}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0b00c6
```

And the string is there in the values/strings.xml

Can anyone tell me how can I fix this weird issue - im using Eclipse for development.

Comment: well i guess you might want to show us your code and the manifest and the strings.xml

Comment: @Krupal yes i use eclipse

Comment: @DarkoPetkovski then close it and reopen!..if still an error then write whole code here and notify us

Answer (score 1):

The answer was that I had a library called `StackBlur` that was causing some issues - but none in were shown in logCat. I've removed the library and now the project is working fine!